# Number Sequence Series-Question 7

Tags: calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

This is a series of questions that are created by me.

Here is question 7:

**(23)，(55)，(155)，(1255)，？，？，(56139611)**

I will give a hint to you guys in one month if nobody can solve it.

Comment: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/number-sequence-puzzles-what-not-to-do

Comment: Please can you give us a hint? (I know it hasn't been quite a month yet but you also have barely any comments on the question and it's driving me and my friends crazy)

Comment: Maybe you can get the solution by the dividing numbers by 11 ? If the number isn't divisible by 11 you get the same decimal places every time.

Comment: Ready for that hint.

Comment: @Letterking Please can you provide a hint?

Comment: Hi my first post on this forum. Don't know how to use the "spoiler" function. But I've found something which at least fits for the two first numbers.. and maybe the third. Are you 100% sure, all the numbers are correct?

Comment: @Prim3numbah The spoiler can be made by using >! but is only possible in answers