# Number Sequence Series-Question 8

Tags: calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

This is a series of questions that are created by me.

Here is question 8:

**(36),(45),?,(17),(50),?,(29)**

I will give a hint to you guys if I feel it is necessary.

$$$$
You can check other unsolved questions below.

[Number Sequence Series-Question 7](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84458/number-sequence-series-question-7)

[Number sequences: 6X000X9, 700XX08,00000015,?,00000015](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84014/number-sequences-000-x00-and-6x000x9-700xx08)

Comment: Sorry I did not see this contest before..I have changed the question.

Comment: If no one has pointed you to it yet, you might want to read [Number Sequence Puzzles: What Not To Do](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5712).  Frankly, this type of puzzle is not that interesting, and you have posted quite a few of them in the last few days.  You might want to think about a different kind of puzzle, or of finding ways to incorporate your sequences into a story that makes it more interesting for the solver.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain The logic behind the number sequence is quite interesting tho

Comment: @ANOOB The logic may be interesting, but until you've solved it, the puzzle is not. Ideally, you want people to *want* to solve your puzzle, not look at it and groan at yet another bland looking number sequence with nothing distinctive about it to guide you toward a solution.

Answer (score 6):

An answer is

> 41 and 25

Reason:

> Basically, the logic is '**The Sum of Squares**'

Example:

> 45=**3**²+**6**² & 41=**4**²+**5**² & 17=**1**²+**4**² & 50=**7**²+**1**²